# how to invoke javascript function with more than one argument from silverlight project?

Tags: javascript, html, silverlight, invoke

i had some trouvle with invoking a javascript function with more than one argument  from a html page  that is what i am doing :

```
wbNavigator.Navigate(new Uri("http://localhost:56433/route.html" ,UriKind.Absolute) );
object results= wbNavigator.InvokeScript("calculer", new string[] {"3.072526", "36.766942", "3.042526", "36.766942"});
```

but when invoking nothing's hapening .Am i missing something ? 
that is my javascript Code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
              var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
              var myOptions = {
                  zoom: 7,
                  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
              }
       function calcluer(lon_A, lat_A, lon_B, lat_B) {
           var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
           directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
           var salle2 = new google.maps.LatLng(lat_A, lon_A);
           var salle3 = new google.maps.LatLng(lat_B, lon_B);
           var request = {
               origin: salle2,
               destination: salle3,
               travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
           };  
       directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
           if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
               // Display the distance:
               document.getElementById('distance').innerHTML +=
                response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value + " meters";
               // Display the duration:
               document.getElementById('duration').innerHTML +=
                response.routes[0].legs[0].duration.value + " seconds";
               directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
           }
       });
       }
       </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use:-

```
object results= wbNavigator.InvokeScript("calculer", "3.072526", "36.766942", "3.042526", "36.766942");
```

Note that doing this immediately after navigate may not have the desired effect.  You should perhaps move this code to the `LoadCompleted` event of the `WebBrowser`.

Comment: thx for your answer ! i tried to do that ! but it's always the same problem perhaps a have a problem with my  javascript code :

Comment: @Mehdi: comments are not a good place for so much text and especiall code which doesn't format at all in comments.  Use the edit feature under your question and place addition info in your question.